# How do I join these two queries with multi joins in each together?

Tags: mysql, join

So I have two queries that I need joined on word_pdf_cords.lineNumber. The two queries consist of joins themselves as well. Don't know the syntax of MySQL in and out so I'm struggling a tad.

Query one

```
Select pdf.html_path,pdf.xml_path, 
word.word_Value,word_pdf.word_pdf_ID,word_pdf_cords.word_pdf_cords_ID,
word_pdf_cords.word_pdf_ID,word_pdf_cords.pageNumber,
word_pdf_cords.lineNumber 

FROM word_pdf

INNER JOIN pdf ON pdf.PDF_ID = word_pdf.PDF_ID

Inner Join word ON word.word_ID = word_pdf.word_ID

Inner Join word_pdf_cords ON word_pdf.word_pdf_ID = 
word_pdf_cords.word_pdf_ID

WHERE word.word_Value ="clocks"
```

Query two

```
Select pdf.html_path,pdf.xml_path, 
word.word_Value,word_pdf.word_pdf_ID,word_pdf_cords.word_pdf_cords_ID,
word_pdf_cords.word_pdf_ID,word_pdf_cords.pageNumber,
word_pdf_cords.lineNumber 

FROM word_pdf

INNER JOIN pdf ON pdf.PDF_ID = word_pdf.PDF_ID

Inner Join word ON word.word_ID = word_pdf.word_ID

Inner Join word_pdf_cords ON word_pdf.word_pdf_ID = 
word_pdf_cords.word_pdf_ID

WHERE word.word_Value ="pirates"
```

I need to join the results of these two queries on pdf_cords.lineNumber.

Comment: if you provide sqlfiddle with some data and expected result that would help a lot

Comment: do you need word.word_Value **clocks** and **pirates** in the same line and same column? or you don't need them at all? but just `lineNumber ` when both values exist?

Comment: I know that they are on the same line so I was using it as a test. I am trying to emulate phrase searching by looking up what PDF the word is in and what line number it is on. So the two seprate queries will be joined on word_pdf.word_pdf_ID as well as word_pdf_cords.lineNumber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work , but not on large amounts of data. If someone knows more about DB query optimization and could give me some guidance that would be nice.

```
Select 

q1.html_path,q1.xml_path,q1.word_Value,q1.pageNumber,q1.lineNumber,
q2.word_Value FROM

 (SELECT pdf.html_path,pdf.xml_path, 
word.word_Value,word_pdf_cords.pageNumber,
word_pdf_cords.lineNumber FROM word_pdf INNER JOIN pdf ON pdf.PDF_ID = 
word_pdf.PDF_ID Inner Join word ON word.word_ID = word_pdf.word_ID Inner 
Join word_pdf_cords ON word_pdf.word_pdf_ID = word_pdf_cords.word_pdf_ID 
WHERE word.word_Value ="John")

as q1

 JOIN (SELECT pdf.html_path,pdf.xml_path, 
word.word_Value,word_pdf_cords.pageNumber,word_pdf_cords.lineNumber FROM 
word_pdf INNER JOIN pdf ON pdf.PDF_ID = word_pdf.PDF_ID Inner Join word ON 
word.word_ID = word_pdf.word_ID Inner Join word_pdf_cords ON 
word_pdf.word_pdf_ID = word_pdf_cords.word_pdf_ID WHERE word.word_Value 
="Smith")

as q2 ON q1.html_path = q2.html_path and q1.pageNumber = 

q2.pageNumber and q1.lineNumber = q2.lineNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the only difference is in the WHERE clause, so instead of joining both queries you can join the where clauses only:

```
WHERE word.word_Value ="pirates" OR word.word_Value ="clocks"
```

Comment: ;-) That is kind a joke I wanted to put as a comment. But I am pretty sure that is not what OP wants.